# Django rest framework post request returns 200 but data is not saved in the database

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

when post request is sent to the api, api returns Ok as the response but no data is inserted into the database.

views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def createTicketList(request):
    serializer = TicketListSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors)
```

serializer.py

```
class TicketListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TicketListTable
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return TicketListTable(**validated_data)
```

models.py

```
class TicketListTable(models.Model):
    ticketListName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ticketListCreated = models.DateTimeField()
    ticketListUpdates = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ticketListName

    class Meta:
        app_label = "backend"
        db_table = "TicketListTable"
```

postman api

[postman api post request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQzv8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you don't save `TicketeListTable` instance in serializer `create` function. If you remove `create` function, the instance will be saved. There is already a create function in `ModelSerializer`.

https://www.cdrf.co/3.12/rest_framework.serializers/ModelSerializer.html#create